# Is there anyway add 2 or more chart with foreach loop

Tags: chart.js

```
<html>
      <head>
             <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <script> 
                 <!--bar stacked-->
                 var data2 = {
                 CC: [{
                 code: '123ASD',
                 labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
                 datasets: [
                    {
                     label: 'AAA',
                     backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
                     data: [32,41,21,78,0,0,0]
                    },
                    {
                     label: 'BBB',
                     backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
                     data: [10,80,12,70,65,44,18]
                    },
                    {
                     label: 'CCC',
                     backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
                     data: [915,400,233,398,334,766,1071]
                     },
               ]}
               ,
               {
                 code: 'ASD123',
                 labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
                 datasets: [
                     {
                      label: 'AAA',
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
                      data: [55,22,40,2,0,0,0]
                     },
                     {
                      label: 'BBB',
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
                      data: [10,2,100,0,17,55,74]
                      },
                      {
                      label: 'CCC',
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
                      data: [232,555,800,900,723,1001,942]
                      },
                      ]
                      },
                  ]
                  };
                   data2.CC.forEach( function(i, item){

                   document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="'+i.code+'"></canvas>'
                   var ctx2 = document.getElementById(i.kodu).getContext('2d');
                   window.myBar = new Chart(ctx2, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: data2.AA[0],
                        options: {
                             title: {
                                 display: true,
                                 text: i.code
                             },
                             tooltips: {
                                 mode: 'index',
                                 intersect: false
                             },
                             responsive: true,
                             scales: {
                                 xAxes: [{
                                     stacked: true,
                                 }],
                                 yAxes: [{
                                     stacked: true
                                 }]
                             }
                       }
                 });
           });
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

when I run I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property '*currentStyle*' of null** and my first chart can't load
I try [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null in ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853703/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-currentstyle-of-null-in-chartjs) but my first chart again dont load 
Is there anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of issues:

1. Chart reference was being overridden by the last chart in the collection
2. A few references to variables did not exist from your original source dump
3. Chart data source reference needed to be changed

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     var chartData = {
       CC: [{
         code: '123ASD',
         labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
         datasets: [{
           label: 'AAA',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
           data: [32,41,21,78,0,0,0]
         },{
           label: 'BBB',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
           data: [10,80,12,70,65,44,18]
         },{
           label: 'CCC',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
           data: [915,400,233,398,334,766,1071]
         }]
       },{
         code: 'ASD123',
         labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
         datasets: [{
           label: 'AAA',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
           data: [55,22,40,2,0,0,0]
         },{
           label: 'BBB',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
           data: [10,2,100,0,17,55,74]
         },{
           label: 'CCC',
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
           data: [232,555,800,900,723,1001,942]
         }]
       }]
     };

     chartData.CC.forEach(function(data, index){
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
           chartId = 'chart' + data.code;

       canvas.id = chartId;

       document.body.appendChild(canvas);

       var context = document.getElementById(chartId).getContext('2d');

       window[chartId] = new Chart(context, {
         type: 'bar',
         data: data,
         options: {
           title: {
             display: true,
             text: data.code
           },
           tooltips: {
             mode: 'index',
             intersect: false
           },
           responsive: true,
           scales: {
             xAxes: [{
               stacked: true,
             }],
             yAxes: [{
               stacked: true
             }]
           }
         }
       });
     });
   });
   ```

Stack snippet is throwing a script error because of chart.js so I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdNdLp)

Answer (score 0):

You charts are not being loaded because your code should be `item` instead of `data2.AA[0]`. Also, you do not have any property with name `kodu` in your data object. Check out working version below:

```js
var data2 = {
    CC: [{
            code: '123ASD',
            labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'AAA',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
                    data: [32, 41, 21, 78, 0, 0, 0]
                },
                {
                    label: 'BBB',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
                    data: [10, 80, 12, 70, 65, 44, 18]
                },
                {
                    label: 'CCC',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
                    data: [915, 400, 233, 398, 334, 766, 1071]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            code: 'ASD123',
            labels: ["7/2/2018", "7/3/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/6/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/10/2018"],
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'AAA',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
                    data: [55, 22, 40, 2, 0, 0, 0]
                },
                {
                    label: 'BBB',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
                    data: [10, 2, 100, 0, 17, 55, 74]
                },
                {
                    label: 'CCC',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,205,1)",
                    data: [232, 555, 800, 900, 723, 1001, 942]
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
};
data2.CC.forEach(function(item, arr) {
    var chartId = item.code;
    var canvas = document.createElement("Canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: item,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: chartId
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: give me error **Cannot set property '_chartjs' of null**

Comment: Not sure, if you are loading your scripts correctly, but you can see the snippet working in my posted code.